# Loading large matrix from text file into Java arrays

Tags: java, arrays, text-files, java.util.scanner, scientific-computing

My data is stored in large matrices stored in text files with millions of rows and 4 columns of comma-separated values.  (Each column stores a different variable, and each row stores a different millisecond's data for all four variables.)  There is also some irrelevant header data in the first dozen or so lines.  I need to write Java code to load this data into four arrays, with one array for each column in the text matrix.

The Java code also needs to be able to tell when the header is done, so that the first data row can be split into entries for the 4 arrays.  Finally, the Java code needs to iterate through the millions of data rows, repeating the process of decomposing each row into four numbers which are each entered into the appropriate array for the column in which the number was located.

How can I alter the code below in order to accomplish this? I want to find the fastest way to accomplish this processing of millions of rows.

Here is my code:

MainClass2.java

```
  package packages;

public class MainClass2{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    readfile2 r = new readfile2();
    r.openFile();
    int x1Count = r.readFile();
    r.populateArray(x1Count);
    r.closeFile();  
}
}
```

readfile2.java

```
  package packages;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class readfile2 {
private Scanner scan1;
private Scanner scan2;

public void openFile(){
    try{
        scan1 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\test\\samedatafile.txt"));
        scan1 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\test\\samedatafile.txt"));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("could not find file");
    }
}
public int readFile(){
    int scan1Count = 0;
    while(scan1.hasNext()){
        scan1.next();
        scan1Count += 1;
    }
    return scan1Count;
}
public double[] populateArray(int scan1Count){
    double[] outputArray1 = new double[scan1Count];
    double[] outputArray2 = new double[scan1Count];
    double[] outputArray3 = new double[scan1Count];
    double[] outputArray4 = new double[scan1Count];
    int i = 0;
    while(scan2.hasNext()){
        //what code do I write here to:
        //  1.) identify the start of my time series rows after the end of the header rows (e.g. row starts with a number AT LEAST 4 digits in length.)
        //  2.) split each time series row's data into a separate new entry for each of the 4 output arrays
        i++;
    }
    return outputArray1, outputArray2, outputArray3, outputArray4;
}
public void closeFile(){
    scan1.close();
    scan2.close();
}
}
```

Here are the first 19 lines of a typical data file:

```
text and numbers on first line
1 msec/sample
3 channels
ECG
Volts
Z_Hamming_0_05_LPF
Ohms
dz/dt
Volts
min,CH2,CH4,CH41,
,3087747,3087747,3087747,
0,-0.0518799,17.0624,0,
1.66667E-05,-0.0509644,17.0624,-0.00288295,
3.33333E-05,-0.0497437,17.0624,-0.00983428,
5E-05,-0.0482178,17.0624,-0.0161573,
6.66667E-05,-0.0466919,17.0624,-0.0204402,
8.33333E-05,-0.0448608,17.0624,-0.0213986,
0.0001,-0.0427246,17.0624,-0.0207532,
0.000116667,-0.0405884,17.0624,-0.0229672,
```

---

### Edit

I tested Shilaghae's code suggestion.  It seems to work.  However, the length of all the resulting arrays is the same as x1Count, so that zeros remain in the places where Shilaghae's pattern matching code is not able to place a number. (This is a result of how I wrote the code originally.)

I was having trouble finding the indices where zeros remain, but there seemed to be a lot more zeros besides the ones expected where the header was.  When I graphed the derivative of the temp[1] output, I saw a number of sharp spikes where false zeros in temp[1] might be.  If I can tell where the zeros in temp[1], temp[2], and temp[3] are, I might be able to modify the pattern matching to better retain all the data.

Also, it would be nice to simply shorten the output array to no longer include the rows where the header was in the input file.  However, the tutorials I have found regarding variable length arrays only show oversimplified examples like:

```
int[] anArray = {100, 200, 300, 400};
```

The code might run faster if it no longer uses scan1 to produce scan1Count.  I do not want to slow the code down by using an inefficient method to produce a variable-length array.  And I also do not want to skip data in my time series in the cases where the pattern matching is not able to split the input row into 4 numbers.  I would rather keep the in-time-series zeros so that I can find them and use them to debug the pattern matching.

Can these things be done in fast-running code?

---

### Second edit

So

```
"-{0,1}\\d+.\\d+,"
```

repeats for times in the expression:

```
"-{0,1}\\d+.\\d+,-{0,1}\\d+.\\d+,-{0,1}\\d+.\\d+,-{0,1}\\d+.\\d+,"
```

Does

```
"-{0,1}\\d+.\\d+,"
```

decompose into the following three statements:

```
"-{0,1}" means that a minus sign occurs zero or one times, while  

"\\d+." means that the minus sign(or lack of minus sign) is followed by several digits of any value followed by a decimal point, so that finally  

"\\d+," means that the decimal point is followed by several digits of any value?
```

If so, what about numbers in my data like "1.66667E-05," or "-8.06131E-05," ?  I just scanned one of the input files, and (out of 3+ million 4-column rows) it contains 638 numbers that contain E, of which 5 were in the first column, and 633 were in the last column.

Comment: Please supply a (shortened!) example of your data so we can see what the headers look like.

Comment: Try "-{0,1}\\d+.\\d+E{0,1}-{0,1}\\d*,-{0,1}\\d+.\\d+E{0,1}-{0,1}\\d*,-{0,1}\\d+.\\d+E{0,1}-{0,1}\\d*,-{0,1}\\d+.\\d+E{0,1}-{0,1}\\d*," for other information about regular expression in java see http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: Thank you very much!  Your new suggestion seems to have significantly reduced the number of locations in which the derivative of outputArray2 spikes.  However, there are still many places where the derivatives of outputArray3 and outputArray4 have sharp spikes.  I suspect that the spikes may be due to the regex not handling all possible cases as well as possible.  I am going to sleep now, but tomorrow I will run some diagnostics and re-read the Vogella tutorial before either closing this item or asking additional questions.  Thank you again very much.

Comment: Approximately 3,500 (0.1%) of the entries in outputArray3 are showing to have zero values even though the values for that variable in the input file is ALWAYS between 16 and 18. There might be half as many problem rows in outputArray4, and perhaps a dozen or more problem rows in outputArray2. Can anyone suggest a way I can upload a data file that people can download to run with my problem code? I have a web server, but I would like to find an ANONYMOUS server where I can just upload a file and link to it without giving the world the ability to look me up through the name of my personal server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read  line to line the file and for every line you could control with a regular expression (http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) if the line presents exactly 4 comma.
If the line presents exactly 4 comma you can split the line with String.split and fill the 4 array otherwise you pass at next line.

```
        public double[][] populateArray(int scan1Count){
            double[] outputArray1 = new double[scan1Count];
            double[] outputArray2 = new double[scan1Count];
            double[] outputArray3 = new double[scan1Count];
            double[] outputArray4 = new double[scan1Count];


            //Read File Line By Line
            try {
                File tempfile = new File("samedatafile.txt");
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tempfile);
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));      
                String strLine;
                int i = 0;
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-{0,1}\\d+.\\d+,-{0,1}\\d+.\\d+,-{0,1}\\d+.\\d+,-{0,1}\\d+.\\d+,");
                      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strLine);
                      if (matcher.matches()){
                          String[] split = strLine.split(",");              
                          outputArray1[i] = Double.parseDouble(split[0]);
                          outputArray2[i] = Double.parseDouble(split[1]);
                          outputArray3[i] = Double.parseDouble(split[2]);
                          outputArray4[i] = Double.parseDouble(split[3]);
                      }
                      i++;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            double[][] temp = new double[4][];
            temp[0]= outputArray1;
            temp[1]= outputArray2;
            temp[2]= outputArray3;
            temp[3]= outputArray4;
            return temp;
        }
```

Comment: I am currently testing this code.  I will respond soon, after I am done testing.  Thank you for posting it.

Comment: I tested your code, and I placed the results of the testing in an edit to my original posting above.  Thank you for helping me so far.  Are you willing to help me with the follow-up questions I posted above?

Comment: You can use an ArrayList of Double to not specify the size of arrays and fill the ArrayList only when the pattern matches.In this way you will not have zero values in your result.

Comment: Thank you.  I am spending some time trying to decode "-{0,1}\\d+.\\d+,-{0,1}\\d+.\\d+,-{0,1}\\d+.\\d+,-{0,1}\\d+.\\d+," because it is mixing up perhaps 2% of the 3 million rows.  Do you mind writing out what each step in the expression means?  I am also starting to try to decode it using web resources including the link you sent above.

Comment: Sure the code "-{0,1}\\d+.\\d+,-{0,1}\\d+.\\d+,-{0,1}\\d+.\\d+,-{0,1}\\d+.\\d+," selects every row formatted as follow: any digit with an optionality sign of minus ahead  followed by a comma == "-{0,1}\\d," 
Are regular expressions see: http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: Thank you.  I just decomposed the expression and posed it as a question for your correction, if you are willing.  However, it was too long to fit here, so I added it as an edit to my original post above.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer to give you points for helping me.  Thank you very much!  However, the actual answer involved modifying this code to use a much simpler regex "," and deleting the header manually because your more complicated regex was skipping 0.1% of the points and thus leaving 3500 spikes in the graph of 3+ million points.  I included the final code in a final edit to my original posting above.

Answer (score 0):

You can split up each line using [String.split()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

To skip the headers, you can either read the first N lines and discard them (if you know how many there are) or you will need to look for a specific marker - difficult to advise without seeing your data.

You may also need to change your approach a little because you currently seem to be sizing the arrays according to the total number of lines (assuming your Scanner returns lines?) rather than omitting the count of header lines.

Answer (score 0):

I'd deal with the problem of the headers by simply attempting to parse **every** line as four numbers, and throwing away any lines where the parsing doesn't work.  If there is a possibility of unparseable lines after the header lines, then you can set a flag the first time you get a "good" line, and then report any subsequent "bad" lines.

Split the lines with `String.split(...)`.  It is not the absolute fastest way to do it, but the CPU time of your program will be spent elsewhere ... so it probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

*(Moved solution on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space).*

The final code was very simple, and simply involved using string.split() with "," as the regular expression.  To do that, I had to manually delete the headers from the input file so that the data only contained rows with 4 comma separated numbers.

In case anyone is curious, the final working code for this is:

```
public double[][] populateArray(int scan1Count){
    double[] outputArray1 = new double[scan1Count];
    double[] outputArray2 = new double[scan1Count];
    double[] outputArray3 = new double[scan1Count];
    double[] outputArray4 = new double[scan1Count];
    
    try {
        File tempfile = new File("C:\\test\\mydatafile.txt");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tempfile);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        int i = 0;
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                String[] split = strLine.split(",");
                outputArray1[i] = Double.parseDouble(split[0]);
                outputArray2[i] = Double.parseDouble(split[1]);
                outputArray3[i] = Double.parseDouble(split[2]);
                outputArray4[i] = Double.parseDouble(split[3]);
            i++;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("e for exception is:"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        double[][] temp = new double[4][];
        temp[0]= outputArray1;
        temp[1]= outputArray2;
        temp[2]= outputArray3;
        temp[3]= outputArray4;
        return temp;
        }
```